# cannot open shared object file : No such file or directory

Tags: linux, database, postgresql, postgis, redhat

I installed postgresql-9.3 in linux server 7.1 redhat & postgis93-2.1.8

after that i created New Database and executed the Query in Query Window

```
   "Create extension postgis"
```

it showing error like below

```
 ERROR: could not load library "/opt/Postgresql/9.3/lib/postgresql/rtpostgis-2.1.so":libpng12.so.0:cannot open shared object file : No such file or directory sql state 58p01
```

I installed backage libpng12.so.0 correctly

file in the location og /usr/lib/

Kindly let me know where i am wrong

Comment: How did you install these packages?

Comment: Hi Mike T : I updated the linux machine, again i installed libpng12.it's working fine